# WooCommerce, Display Multiple Tabs Conditionally

Tags: woocommerce, conditional-statements, tabs, categories

First things first. I am NOT proficient in PHP but I can sometimes modify it to do what I want.

I have a WooCommerce site with thousands of products. These are broken down into multiple "Brands". These "Brands" come from an additional plugin called "Perfect Brands WooCommerce" but I have used the "Brand" name as a category as well so I can utilise it.

I found some code on StackOverflow to enable me to display a Tab based on the category of the product, which I then modified for the various categories. As you can see, anything in the "bisley-workwear" category will show the "additional_brand_info_tab" with the content from the "bisley-workwear". The same goes for the other two categories.

What I want to do is show more than one tab for a particular category. i.e. if the product category is "bisley-workwear" I want to show multiple tabs. These would change depending on the category.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Conditional Brand Info Tabs

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'custom_tabs' );
function custom_tabs( $tabs ) {
    // Adds the new tab
if ( has_term( 'bisley-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // // Shows this tab if the product is in the "bisley-workwear" category (Use category slug).
$tabs['additional-brand-info'] = array(
'title' => __( 'Bisley Workwear', 'woocommerce' ),
'priority' => 50,
'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_tab'
);
}
 elseif ( has_term( 'as-colour', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "as-colour" category (Use category slug).
$tabs['additional-brand-info'] = array(
'title' => __( 'AS Colour', 'woocommerce' ),
'priority' => 50,
'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_tab'
);
}
  elseif ( has_term( 'syzmik-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "syzmik-workwear" category (Use category slug).
$tabs['additional-brand-info'] = array(
'title' => __( 'Sizmik Workwear', 'woocommerce' ),
'priority' => 50,
'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_tab'
);
} 
    return $tabs;
}
function additional_brand_info_tab() {
    // The new tab content
if ( has_term( 'bisley-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "bisley-workwear" category (Use category slug).
    echo 'This is Bisley Workwear';
    }
  elseif ( has_term( 'as-colour', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "as-colour" category (Use category slug).
    echo do_shortcode('This is AS Colour');
  }
  elseif ( has_term( 'syzmik-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "syzmik-workwear" category (Use category slug).
    echo ('This is Syzmik Workwear');
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure what to do after modifying the code as above. At the moment this works for displaying one tab based on a category. Multiple tabs would be great.

Comment: This is how to check multiple categories if ( has_term( array( 'bisley-workwear', 'as-colour', 'syzmik-workwear' ), 'product_cat' ) ) { }

Comment: Thank you for the comment but it's not what I mean. I want to display multiple tabs if the product matches one category only.

Comment: Then register diferent tabs ? you see one tab because all tabs have the same id and callback and priority to order the tabs how you want .

Comment: Thanks Snuffy, at first I had no idea about how to do this but your last comment made me look at the code a bit harder. As I said in the beginning, I am not proficient in PHP but I'm willing to have a go.  I'll repost what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to Snuffy's prompting, I have found a solution. I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax or whether it could be done better, but it works.

This code will display two tabs if a product belongs to the "bisley-workwear" category:

```
// Conditional Brand Info Tabs

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'custom_tabs' );
function custom_tabs( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
if ( has_term( 'bisley-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the 
product is in the "bisley-workwear" category (Use category slug).
$tabs['brand-info'] = array(
'title' => __( 'Bisley Workwear', 'woocommerce' ),
'priority' => 50,
'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_tab'
);
$tabs['brand-info-2'] = array(
'title' => __( 'Bisley Workwear 2', 'woocommerce' ),
'priority' => 50,
'callback' => 'additional_brand_info2_tab'
);
}
 elseif ( has_term( 'as-colour', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the         
product is in the "as-colour" category (Use category slug).
$tabs['brand-info'] = array(
'title' => __( 'AS Colour', 'woocommerce' ),
'priority' => 50,
'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_tab'
);
}
  elseif ( has_term( 'syzmik-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if 
the product is in the "syzmik-workwear" category (Use category slug).
$tabs['brand-info'] = array(
'title' => __( 'Sizmik Workwear', 'woocommerce' ),
'priority' => 50,
'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_tab'
);
} 
    return $tabs;
}
function additional_brand_info_tab() {
    // The new tab content
if ( has_term( 'bisley-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the 
product is in the "bisley-workwear" category (Use category slug).
    echo 'This is Bisley Workwear';
    }
  elseif ( has_term( 'as-colour', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the 
product is in the "as-colour" category (Use category slug).
    echo ('This is AS Colour');
  }
  elseif ( has_term( 'syzmik-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if 
the product is in the "syzmik-workwear" category (Use category slug).
    echo ('This is Syzmik Workwear');
  }
}
function additional_brand_info2_tab() {
    // The new tab content
if ( has_term( 'bisley-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the 
product is in the "bisley-workwear" category (Use category slug).
    echo 'This is Bisley Workwear 2';
    }
  elseif ( has_term( 'as-colour', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the 
product is in the "as-colour" category (Use category slug).
    echo ('This is AS Colour');
  }
  elseif ( has_term( 'syzmik-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if 
the product is in the "syzmik-workwear" category (Use category slug).
    echo ('This is Syzmik Workwear');
  }
}
```

Note the addition of:

```
$tabs['brand-info-2'] = array(
'title' => __( 'Bisley Workwear 2', 'woocommerce' ),
'priority' => 50,
'callback' => 'additional_brand_info2_tab'
);
}
```

and

```
function additional_brand_info2_tab() {
// The new tab content
if ( has_term( 'bisley-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the 
product is in the "bisley-workwear" category (Use category slug).
    echo 'This is Bisley Workwear 2';
    }
  elseif ( has_term( 'as-colour', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the 
product is in the "as-colour" category (Use category slug).
    echo ('This is AS Colour 2');
  }
  elseif ( has_term( 'syzmik-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if 
the product is in the "syzmik-workwear" category (Use category slug).
    echo ('This is Syzmik Workwear 2');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And the final working code which displays 2 tabs based on the category of the product:

```
// Conditional Brand Info Tabs

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'custom_tabs' );
function custom_tabs( $tabs ) {// Adds the new tab
    if ( has_term( 'bisley-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "bisley-workwear" category (Use category slug).
        $tabs['brand-info-1'] = array(
            'title' => __( 'Bisley Workwear', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_tab'
        );
        $tabs['brand-info-2'] = array(
            'title' => __( 'Bisley Workwear 2', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_2_tab'
        );
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'as-colour', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "as-colour" category (Use category slug).
        $tabs['brand-info'] = array(
            'title' => __( 'AS Colour', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_tab'
        );
        $tabs['brand-info-2'] = array(
            'title' => __( 'AS Colour 2', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_2_tab'
        );
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'syzmik-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "syzmik-workwear" category (Use category slug).
        $tabs['brand-info'] = array(
            'title' => __( 'Sizmik Workwear', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_tab'
        );
        $tabs['brand-info-2'] = array(
            'title' => __( 'Sizmik Workwear 2', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'additional_brand_info_2_tab'
        );
    } 
    return $tabs;
}

function additional_brand_info_tab() {  // The new tab content
    if ( has_term( 'bisley-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "bisley-workwear" category (Use category slug).
        echo 'This is Bisley Workwear';
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'as-colour', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "as-colour" category (Use category slug).
        echo ('This is AS Colour');
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'syzmik-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "syzmik-workwear" category (Use category slug).
        echo ('This is Syzmik Workwear');
    }
}

function additional_brand_info_2_tab() { // The new tab content
    if ( has_term( 'bisley-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "bisley-workwear" category (Use category slug).
        echo 'This is Bisley Workwear 2';
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'as-colour', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "as-colour" category (Use category slug).
        echo ('This is AS Colour 2');
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'syzmik-workwear', 'product_cat' ) ) { // Shows this tab if the product is in the "syzmik-workwear" category (Use category slug).
        echo ('This is Syzmik Workwear 2');
    }
}'
```